# Output log scopes with NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

Is there a way to configure NLog to output an array of current active scopes, similar to what the default console logger provider does?

I trying to get something like

```
{
  "EventId": 0,
  "LogLevel": "Information",
  "Category": "Default",
  "Message": "context = [User, Jose]",
  "State": {
    "Message": "context = [User, Jose]",
    "Context": "[User, Jose]",
    "{OriginalFormat}": "context = {Context}"
  },
  "Scopes": [
    {
      "Message": "request 1",
      "RequestID": 1,
      "{OriginalFormat}": "request {RequestID}"
    },
    {
      "Message": "auth type ssl",
      "AuthType": "ssl",
      "{OriginalFormat}": "auth type {AuthType}"
    }
  ]
}
```

see the example https://dotnetfiddle.net/6EThlV

Can NLog JSonLayout provide similar output?

Comment: I think the current option is to write a custom NLog LayoutRenderer that enumerates the NDLC and generates pure Json-output. Then embed the custom LayoutRenderer in a JsonLayout Attribute with encode=false. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer But I think it would make sense to extend the NLog JsonLayout to support this output of the box, maybe for NLog 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLog.Extensions.Logging v5.0 introduces [MicrosoftConsoleJsonLayout](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MicrosoftConsoleJsonLayout) that emulates `AddJsonConsole`:

```xml
<nlog>
<targets>
   <target name="jsonConsole" xsi:type="Console">
      <layout xsi:type="MicrosoftConsoleJsonLayout" includeScopes="true">
         <attribute name="extraPropertyName" layout="${threadid}" />
         <state name="extraStateName" layout="${hostname}" />
      </layout>
   </target>
</targets>
<rules>
   <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="jsonConsole" />
</rules>
</nlog>
```

If also using NLog v5.1.4 then one can also apply the setting `indentJson="true"`.

Notice NLog v5 also includes [${scopenested:format=@}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ScopeNested-Layout-Renderer) that will output scopes as json-array